# Fatel:Error Increase memory limit for post type in wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, out-of-memory, custom-post-type

I have built a site using wordpress in which it has a post type "Properties". In wordpress back end everything works fine including ordinary posts . But when I try to open "Properties" post type the following error is being thrown. Properties post type has more than 4000 posts. (Everything looks fine on front end)

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 81 bytes) in /home/homesdirectoryco/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2350

I have memory of 512 MB in php.ini file,
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512MB' );
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );  in wp settings
and 
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');   in wp-cache.php

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's definitely a php memory limit. You can try to increase it yourself or you can ask your hosting provider to increase it for you. You can check your php memory by creating an `info.php` file and add `phpinfo();` to in.

Go to `mydomain.co.za/info.php` and check your PHP memory limit.

There are several ways to increase your php memory limit. If memory limit in `wp-config.php` is not working for you, you can try another method.

1. `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', "256M");` in wp-config.php file
2. `ini_set('memory_limit', "256M");` during runtime in wp-config.php file
3. `php_value memory_limit 256M` in .htaccess file
4. `memory_limit = 256M` in php.ini file

If none above increase your PHP memory limit, please ask your hosting provider.

You can use this [link](http://tribulant.com/blog/general-news/wordpress-increase-php-memory-limit/) as reference on how to increase PHP memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

The clues in the error message. You need to increase your PHP memory limit. Depending on your server setup this may be in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was happening b/c of post meta cache issues. This article suggested code which solved my issue - and apparently many other's as well.

https://junaid.dev/wordpress-admin-fix-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-error/?unapproved=369&moderation-hash=bd9064ea40d413150d8a42599c13f4f5#comment-369

Here is the code he provides:

```
function jb_pre_get_posts( WP_Query $wp_query ) {
    if ( in_array( $wp_query->get( 'post_type' ), array( 'my_post_type_1', 'my_post_type_2' ) ) ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'update_post_meta_cache', false );
    }
}

// Only do this for admin.
if ( is_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'jb_pre_get_posts' );
}
```